# Handling null value in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in which one column can have null values. But I don't see the grid populating when there are null values. My code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridData,
        columns: [{
            field: "name",
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            field: "result",
            title: "Result",
            template: "# if (result == null) { #" +
                "<span data-content=' '></span> } #" +
                "# } else { #" +
                "<span data-content=\"#: result#\"> </span>"
        }]
    });
});
```

Can anyone help where I went wrong with this.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if you really need to set `data-content` yourself... if you just want to set an empty string instead of a null value, you can do it with a much simpler template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridData,
        columns: [{
            field: "name",
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            field: "result",
            title: "Result",
            template: "#= (result == null) ? ' ' : result #"
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the same. But it says "result is undefined" and the grid is not displayed still.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I thought you were refering to the data of the column.  Can you show us how you get the `gridData` and can you check if it is defined when you reach the `kendoGrid` initialization?

Comment: I'm using a post call to get the data. The data source is something like this:

Comment: Its working fine without template. But not when I use template.

Answer (score 4):

To make it easier for control/readable you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridData,
        columns: [{
            field: "name",
            title: "Name"
        }, {
            title: "Result",
            template: function (dataItem) {
                if (dataItem.result == null)
                    return 'Placeholder';
                else
                    return dataItem.result;
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Personally, don't like Kendo interpolation '#', it's hard to read when there is more logic in the template, which might lead to more interpolation '#'. Make code not readable caused the start point and the endpoint are both used '#'.